# Benchmark disks on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, benchmarking

I am looking for a program to benchmark whole disk and show access time for different sectors on a disk. (I use [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) for that purpose on Microsoft Windows)

Comment: Could you provide more details like do you mind if it's a paid software or does it have to be free?

Comment: hd tune pro is paid software, hd tune is free for personal use. But - i'm looking for alternative to run under linux.

Comment: So no preference whether it's free or paid software?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hdparm`, `dd`, `bonnie++`, `fio`, `iozone` or `orion` to benchmark your disk on Linux. All these programs are free and open source. See [How can I benchmark my HDD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108838/16704), [I/O Performance Benchmarking Linux](https://serverfault.com/q/219739/126950), and [Linux File System Read Write Performance Test](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-file-system-read-write-performance-test) for information on how to use them.